# Raspberry Pico branch discrepancy

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi-pico

So I have some Raspberry Pico PIO code.  There was a branch that wasn't working; it was only yielding x = 2.  As an afterthought I refactored it, in a way that shouldn't have changed the end result, but it did.  Here's the former code:

```
    ...
    jmp pin rd           side 0b0101 [1]
    set x, 0b010         side 0b0101 [1]
    jmp rdx              side 0b0101 [1]
rd:
    set x, 0b100         side 0b0101 [1]
rdx:
    ...
```

and here's after the refactor.

```
    ...
    set x, 0b100         side 0b0101 [1]
    jmp pin rd           side 0b0101 [1]
    set x, 0b010         side 0b0101 [1]
rd:
    ...
```

I think I've tested it three times both ways, and the former code only ever gives x = 2, while the latter code gives x = 2 or x = 4 depending on the value of the pin.  (There's a little bit of assumption, here; the pin is set by an external chip and indicates the presence of data.  I can get the second block to change reliably, though, and the first doesn't, and the only thing I change in the pico code is which of the two blocks are commented out, so....)  The former, if `pin`, it should jump to where it sets x = 4, skipping x = 2, and if not `pin`, set x = 2, and then skip x = 4, yeah?  The latter block similarly, but it starts off setting x = 4.  But the second block acts like pin is sometimes 1 and sometimes 0, while the first block acts like pin is only ever 0.  Do I misunderstand how jmp works or something???  Here's my full code.  https://github.com/Erhannis/pico-examples/commit/a83ed67fdc4c3527e52b9462116f692309ae4d0f  (There's also comms code for the FT232H I've connected to the Pico, which, incidentally, is the actual output I'm observing.  The only thing I change in that code is whether I write any data from the computer to the FT232H.  I test both versions of that code with both versions of the Pico code, so I don't think that's the problem.)

Also, should I instead ask this on the Electronics Stackexchange?

Comment: The codes make sense but they read the pin at different times so maybe at that location the pin is in fact always zero?

Comment: @Jester Well...annoyingly enough, I added a `nop [1]` in front of the first block, and now it works.  So...I guess that WAS the problem.  If you want to turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Side note - it was probably related to the default 3-6 cycle round trip latency the PIO has on I/O.